# Index Rebuild in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, performance, indexing, amazon-aurora

I want to know will REINDEX in PostgreSQL will improve my performance. I have never done reindexing since I have created them. Just FYI i am using PostgreSQL on Aurora Serverless.

Comment: Probably not, only if the indexes are quite bloated.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe- thanks, how to check it? Also, i checked the size of the indexes and they are around 1300 MB. Thanks

Comment: You can check that with the `pgstatindex` function from the `pgstattuple` extension.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe- Thanks. Can you please tell me the exact benefit of REINDEX feature in PostgreSQL.

Comment: It removes bloat and index corruption. You only do it if you have an indication, not as a regular maintenance procedure.